# Is source url case sensitive for html5 video tag?

Tags: html, django, html5-video

A video file name with known name '/media/hello.' (case sensitive), but unknown  case extension, such as '.mOv', '.MOV' or '.mov'

Real file is '/media/hello.MOV'.

The following video sometimes work if Django web server running from MacPro, but if running from Ubunto production server, video file name '/media/hellow.mov' does not work (More tests makes me more confused, as it seems Ubutntu production server status is unclear).

```
  <video id="video" defaultMuted autoplay playsinline controls>
    <source src="/media/hello.mov" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

I want to know if  file extension is case sensitive.

Without knowing real extension, I used following code to find real extension, but web site not really working at more due to inefficiency of following code. Is there better way to find real extension?

```
def find_real_extension(fullpath_file, extensions):

  find = False
  real_ext = None
  fullpath_file = fullpath_file + '.*'
  for filename in glob.iglob(fullpath_file):
    base, real_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = real_ext.lower()
    if ext and ext in extensions:
      find = True
      break

  if find:
    return real_ext
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: Mac OS X uses by default a **case-inensitive** file system. You could say the server is case-sensitive, but it eventually results in a file system lookup, and an APFS is case-insensitive, so it simply provides the file.

Answer (score 1):

**In short**: It depends on the file system used. By default Mac OS X uses a case-insenstive file system, whereas Ubuntu uses a case-sensitive one.

---

First of all it is important to note that Django will, by default *not* serve media files in production, as is [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development). So in production you usually configure `nginx`, etc. and these can be configured to be case (in-)sensitive.

If we take a look at how media files and static files are served in development mode, then we use the [**`static(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#static). This function basically checks if we are running in debug mode, and if that is the case, it adds a url that is referring to the [**`serve(..)`** view function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve).

If we take a look at the [source code of `serve` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/static.py#L19), we see:

> ```
> def serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
>     # ...
>     path = posixpath.normpath(path).lstrip('/')
>     fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
>     if fullpath.is_dir():
>         # ...
>     if not fullpath.exists():
>         # ...
>     # Respect the If-Modified-Since header.
>     statobj = fullpath.stat()
>     # ...
> ```

Here the `Path` is imported from the [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. As is specified, the `pathlib` respects the casefolding of the flavor:

> ```
> >>> PurePosixPath('foo') == PurePosixPath('FOO')
> False
> >>> PureWindowsPath('foo') == PureWindowsPath('FOO')
> True
> >>> PureWindowsPath('FOO') in { PureWindowsPath('foo') }
> True
> >>> PureWindowsPath('C:') < PureWindowsPath('d:')
> True
> ```

It thus depends on the underlying file system. [An answer on *AskDifferent*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304) specifies that *Mac OS X* has by default a case-**in**sensitive HFS+ file system. So that means that if you look for `somefile.mov`, but `somefile.MOV` exists, it will provide that file. Unix-based file systems on the other hand (like the one in Ubuntu) are normally case-sensitive. There is a [case-insensitive ext3 driver](http://bill.herrin.us/freebies/), but I personally would advice not to start using these things, not because the driver is bad (I have not used it, I therefore can not say), but because a lot of Unix architecture has been build on case-sensitive file systems. That thus means that programs might create files `a.txt` and `A.txt`, and might get confused between these files.